# Removing a set users information on logout

Tags: angularjs

Good day, am currently struggling to understand why I can not set a user value as null on logout. I have a method used to set the user information so it's accessed globally and a get method to get the users information later on but right now regardless of which user is logged in the previous user data remains.

This is my current service controller:

```
    .factory('UserInfo', [function() {
    var user;
    return {
      get: function(){
        return user;
      },
      set: function(userInfo){
        user = userInfo;
      },
      remove :function(){
         user = null;
         return user;
      }
    };
  }
])
.factory('Authentication',['UserInfo',function(UserInfo){
  return {
    user: UserInfo.get()
  };
}]);
```

The function that I am trying to calling out is the remove function in the UserInfo service. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A factory is a singleton, the first instance created gets used every single time you ask for it. So if you do the following:

```
.factory('Authentication',['UserInfo',function(UserInfo){
    return {
        user: UserInfo.get()
    };
}]);
.controller('Blabla', ['Authentication', function(Authentication) {
    var user = Authentication.user;
}]
```

you will set **user** equal to what **UserInfo.get()** returns at that point. So everytime you call **Authentication.user()** it will return the same object, regardless of what the UserInfo actually contains.

You can solve this by passing a function instead of the function result. Like so:

```
.factory('Authentication',['UserInfo',function(UserInfo){
    return {
        user: UserInfo.get
    };
}]);
.controller('Blabla', ['Authentication', function(Authentication) {
    var user = Authentication.user();
}]
```

notice how the **()** (parenthesis) are gone on the **UserInfo.get** and they're added on the **Authentication.user()**.

Comment: Once I removed the **()** (parenthesis) the data I was binding to my ionic view disappeared. Is there no way to get the angular to accept the null value in the remove function?

Comment: The place where you call **Authentication.user** now becomes **Authentication.user()** notice the added **()** (parenthesis)

Comment: Thanks, that worked out. It seemed that the first instance of the authentication function was called but as long as the app did not close it was still cached in memory.